# AngularJS.... Unable to inject view.

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

First post on stacko so appologies for any noob mistakes.

I have started playing around with AngularJS to learn some web development.  I have setup a blank project using netbeans and added some files to my project.  structure looks like:

- Root

  - public_html
  - App

    - controllers
      homecontroller.js
      hydrotelcontroller.js
    - css
    - fonts
    - js
      angular-route.js
      angular-route.min.js
      app.js
      bootstrap.js
      bootstrap.min.js
      jquery-2.2.0.js
      npm.js
    - Views
      Hydrotel.html
      home.html

My webpage is very basic at this point.  I just want it to load the home screen and use the home.html as the view which is injected on loading the page.  I also have a drop down in the header which I want to be able to select the hydrotel.html

No matter what I try the views are not working..... I have looked around and tried a bunch of tutorials but im stuck.

my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/css/bootstrap.css" >
    </head>

    <!-- Define an angular controller -->
    <body ng-controller="homeController">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <ul class="nav">
                        <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> Metering <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#/hydrotel">Hydrotel</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">WISKI</a></li>
                                </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <!-- MAIN CONTENT AND INJECTED VIEWS -->
        <div class="main">           
            <div ng-view></div>
        </div>


        <!-- Angular Declaration -->
        <script src="app/js/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <!-- Include the AngularJS routing library -->        
        <script src="App/js/angular-route.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <!-- Jquery -->
        <script src="app/js/jquery-2.2.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <!-- Bootstrap js -->
        <script src="app/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <!-- Modules-->
        <script src="App/js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <!-- Controllers -->
        <script src="App/controllers/homeController.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    </body> 
</html>
```

my app.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider',
        function ($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
            .when('/home',{
                templateurl: 'app/views/home.html',
                controller: 'homeController'
    })
            .when('/hydrotel', {
                templateurl: 'app/views/hydrotel.html',
                controller: 'hydrotelController'
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/home'
    });
}]);
```

my homecontroller.js

```
   //script.js
    //create the module and name it MetApp
    //create the controller and inject angular's $scope
    app.controller('homeController',['$scope',function($scope){
        //create a message to display in our view
        $scope.message = 'Everyone come see how good I look!';
    }]);
```

my home.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
    <div class="container">
    <h1>My new home page</h1>
    <h2>{{ message }}</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

my hydrotelcontroller.js

```
app.controller('hydrotelContoller',['$scope',function($scope){
    //create a message to display in our view
    $scope.message = 'This is my hydrotel controller';
}]);
```

my hydrotel.html

```
<h2>This is my hydrotel page</h2>
<h3>{{ message }}</h3>
```

Any help with this as well as tips on writing better questions is greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: any error messages shown on your browser console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one was not easy to spot :)

```
.when('/home',{
    templateUrl: 'home.html',
    controller: 'homeController'
 })
```

So problem was simply typo `templateurl`, while it should be `templateUrl` (you have it two times in your router)

I had to tweak your relative paths, to make it working in Plunker.

Here is working [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/P08Nc6cp3bAP3WhBzQK6?p=preview)

Another minor thing, that is not affecting you right now (but still not good) is:

`<body ng-controller="homeController">`

You're specifying controllers in your router for views, so not sure you need it here.

P.S. Question asked very well, enough information provided. Welcome to Angular!

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. worked straight away..... should know by now the importance of case sensitivity :-).